# getting error while trying to work with xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below error is shown:

```
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id='center_column]'/div[1] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id='center_column]'/div[1]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Code trial:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='center_column]'/div[1]")).getCssValue("background-color")
```

Comment: `[@id='center_column]'` -> `[@id='center_column']`

Answer (score 1):

As [@Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5168011/guy) has pointed out you have a `SyntaxError` the XPath's `id` is a string within the locator hens the `''` now your XPath should look something like:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='center_column']/div[1]")
```

Not

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='center_column]'/div[1]")
```

Comment: This should nail the OP

Comment: @user1677627 glad to help!

Comment: Upvote or accept the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of future readers. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote